# How to change font size of text in a latex table

Tags: tables, pdftex

I would like to have font size of 9 for both caption and text in table. However, as shown below, table text is bigger. Previous answers suggest using a `\resizebox{\textwidth}` but that just fits the text to width of space and does not change it to a particular font size? Is there a way I can select all the text in table and set it to `fontsize=small` ? (Using `\selectfont` ?). Please download this to run code [click me](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k1t3ic2fbv9zpd5/ijcai17.sty?dl=0). Appreciate your time.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ijcai17}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
Test document
\begin{table}[h!]
\captionsetup{font=small}
\centering
\caption{AUC values for LR, LR-Regularized, RF-Default, RF-FS for 1s, 3s, 5s, 10s segment lengths and 2-class problems.}
\label{table:2}
\resizebox{0.47\textwidth}{!}{%
%\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{c||c|c|c|c}
\toprule
 & 1s & 3s & 5s & 10s\\
\hline
LR & $0.9223$ & $0.9895$ & $0.9840$ & $0.9913$ \\ \hline
LR-Regularized & $0.9207$ & $0.9887$ & $0.9928$ & $0.9863$ \\ \hline
RF-Default & $0.9072$ & $0.9767$ & $0.9634$ & $0.9735$ \\ \hline
RF-FS & $0.9075$ & $0.9760$ & $0.9681$ & $0.9740$ \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: try `\begin{table}[h!] \small ....`. But in your example, the `\resizebox` modifies the size of the table (font-size including), just like if it was a picture. So this is normal your font is shrunk.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it does. But caption size and size of table text are not same. Both need to be 9 font. Can I do something about that? Thanks.

Comment: you have used the caption package so you can use its features to globally specify caption formatting to use `\small` (don't apply `\resizebox` to tables unless there is absolutely no other option:-)

Comment: @ebo I tried but get same result.

Comment: @David Carlisle I thought caption package applies only to captions in tables and figures. Can I use it to change font size for text inside table also? Thanks.

Comment: no use `\small\begin{tabular}` to get a small text in the tabular (or you could use float package and globally specify formatting for all tables to include \small

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try this MWE, you can see that both caption and table content have same fontsize. Change `Large` into `small` to get 9pt font.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{ijcai17}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \section{Test}
     Test document
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \Large
        \captionsetup{font=Large}
        \centering
        \caption{ AUC values for LR, LR-Regularized, RF-Default, RF-FS for 1s, 3s, 5s, 10s segment lengths and 2-class problems.}
        \label{table:2}
        %\resizebox{0.47\textwidth}{!}{%
            \begin{tabular}{c||c|c|c|c}
                \toprule
                & 1s & 3s & 5s & 10s\\
                \hline
                LR & $0.9223$ & $0.9895$ & $0.9840$ & $0.9913$ \\ \hline
                LR-Regularized & $0.9207$ & $0.9887$ & $0.9928$ & $0.9863$ \\ \hline
                RF-Default & $0.9072$ & $0.9767$ & $0.9634$ & $0.9735$ \\ \hline
                RF-FS & $0.9075$ & $0.9760$ & $0.9681$ & $0.9740$ \\ 
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}%
        %}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it worked great. Using both resizebox and \small gave trouble I guess. Thanks!

Comment: Yup, as David said, *"don't apply `\resizebox` to tables unless there is absolutely no other option"* !